# Use mouse to switch KVM?

Tags: mouse, switch, kvm-switch

Is there a KVM that allows me to switch computers using a mouse button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you could consider using [synergy](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net), which is a mouse driven software KVM. It's a really impressing open-source software that save me many bucks.